# ELKI GUI no clustering results for Hierarchical clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis, elki

I'm new to ELKI and I need to do some basic clustering of a dataset that I already tested and clustered in Weka. I'm using the "GUI version" and I read the tutorial *Analyzing the "mouse" data set* on ELKI site: http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/wiki/Tutorial#Analyzingthemousedataset

I clustered my dataset with EM and successfully visualized and output the results (from the tutorial I just changed the parameter *resultHandler: ResultWriter*). The results I got in the folder are are: cluster.txt, cluster-evaluation.txt and settings.txt.

I have problems with the output results for hierarchical algorithms (SLINK,CLINK, etc.). The output that I got is just the settings.txt, but I need the cluster.txt.

I need to change some other parameters, because on the log view there are no errors?

Comment: Did you *extract* partitions? Or only compute the *hierarchy*? Hierarchical clustering is a **two-step process** (if you want "clusters" and not a tree) and you probably did only the first step. What parameters did you use?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse I just run the task for compute the CLINK algorithm with all default settings. 

Is there some tutorial or guide for hierarchical algorithms or configuring parameters in the main view?


Edit: By extract you mean the parameter _evaluator_ with different options for extraction?

Comment: There are some algorithms in ELKI to extract a flat clustering (which is what you expect) from the hierarchy. I don't recall the names right now, but right next to CLINK? A simple approach is to cut the dendrogram at a threshold, but ELKI had some more complex methods, too.

Answer (score 1):

To get *partitions* from a hierarchical clustering result, you also need to specify a cluster extraction method:

```
-algorithm clustering.hierarchical.extraction.HDBSCANHierarchyExtraction
-algorithm CLINK
-hdbscan.minclsize 50
```

Note that we have *two* `-algorithm` parameters now, and order is important. The extraction algorithm has a "nested" algorithm call to do the actual hierarchical clustering.

[image: CLINK clustering result]

On the long run, we want to move to an operator-based approach (in particular for GUIs). For the command line, the nested-invocation is more safe, as you cannot attempt to extract without running a hierarchical clustering.

As for `CLINK`, the cluster quality is usually not too good (it also *is* order dependent, so shuffling the data and running multiple times will give different results). I'd also give AGNES or Anderberg with complete linkage a try; AGNES is always O(n^3), Anderberg is usually in O(n^2) (only worst case is O(n^3)) and both produce much better results (they are expected to produce the same results except for tied distances, CLINK is different):

[image: Complete-Link clustering with Anderberg algorithm]